# Nothing appears when placing a background image in a <div> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap, I'm trying to set a background-image for the first row of an html page. The .background CSS class, contains info on setting up the background image. When I make it a class of `<body>`, it works fine and fills the whole page with a background image. When I try to put it in the first `<div>`, though, The image is not displayed at all.

From what I understand, you can set a background image for a `<div>`. What am I doing incorrectly that is making this not work?

CSS:

```
.background 
{
background-image : url("image.jpg");
background-repeat : no-repeat;
background-size : cover;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class ="row background">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
  <h1 class="titletext text-center" id="text" style="color : #000070; margin-top : 250px; display : none" ><b>Harness the power of the web</b></h1>
  <input class="center-block" type="image" id="down" src="down-arrow.png" style="margin-top : 350px; display : none" ></input>
</div>
</div>

<!-- start new row -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <!-- img> /img -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <p>
     Blob
    </p>
  </div>
<script>
$("#text").fadeIn(6000);
window.setTimeout(function ()
{
  $("#down").fadeIn(6000);
}, 6000);
</script>
</body>
```

Also, here is an attempt at putting it in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yc1jnp6o/2/. For some reason Neither the image (which I changed for the fiddle) or the headline will display in the fiddle. This isn't the case on the apache server I have set up.

Comment: What is this: `<img> /img>`?

Comment: That was a tag I meant to add an image into later. I forgot to take it out. I have on my computer and it changes nothing. (Also taking it out of the question).

Comment: To make your jsfiddle work, you need to add all your css and js resources as an External Resources from left side menu.

Comment: `display` is set to `none` for your `#text` element, so it is initally not visible. The script you use to show it requires jquery, but you do not include it in you fiddle. Here a corrected [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yc1jnp6o/4/) as you can see the background is visible as soon as the text is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare width and height when using background:

```
.background {
  background-image: url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use width, because he has used `col-xs-12` in row , that means he want to 100% width

```css
.background {
   background-image : url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg");
   background-repeat : no-repeat;
   background-size : cover;
   min-height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

May be you can make use of pseudo code

```
.row.background:before{
  display:block;
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image : url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg");
  background-repeat : no-repeat;
  background-size : cover;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

it covers whole row class

[Check the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yc1jnp6o/3/)

Comment: Why are you so hard?!! , he just need with and height

Comment: yes but cannot change width and height all the time when he adds new element